# ASP.NET Web API caching

Tags: architecture, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm working in a project that we are building a Web API layer to be consumed from diffrent type of clients.

my architecture like this (Clients)<-Web API<-Service layer<-Repository<-Data store

I need to cache data depending on the user identity that the web API authenticated
or may be some filter requested from web API

what is the best approach to build such caching ?

Answer (score 0):

it's not very clear what you want to achieve...if you can refine your question and add more details.

in the mean time, if you want to cache data that depends on the authenticated user, perhaps you can use the Session object (if it's a simple scenario).
if it's filter dependant you can use nay number of caching providers (see below) and use the filter as the cache key.

there also the Cache object, and more advanced solution. if you use NHibernate there's data entity caching out the box almost. it very much depends on your implementation and specific requirements.

read [this aritcle](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449320317/ch_Caching.html) for more details about possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement caching (using simple memory caching, or redis) in your Service Layer, of course you need to pass the Identity of the user to Service Layer.
If you don't want to pass the Identity to your Service Layer, you will need another layer for the cache (between Web API and Service Layer).